# Pasting to Wrong cell

Tags: google-apps-script

So, this script simply needs to copy a line of cells from one spreadsheet, paste it into another, dynamically determining the next cell to use.  For whatever reason I cannot get it to stop after it has pasted once, or pasting at the end of the range instead of at the top. Complete noob here, so any help is appreciated!  This is the full script, so you can see, it should be pretty simple!

Again, the problem is that it either pastes the range to EVERY cell in the range (because it doesn't know to stop), or it pastes it only to the bottom of the range instead of at the top, where it's supposed to.

````
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("SnapshotSpreadsheet!A2:L2");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Monthly Balance Sheet");
  for (i=2; i<30; i++) {
    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(i - 1,1);
    var result = destRange.isBlank();
    if (result == "false"){
      var destRange =destSheet.getRange(i,1);}  
    else if (result == "true") {
      exit}
  }
 source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true})```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to copy the values of `SnapshotSpreadsheet!A2:L2` to the first blank cell from row 1 to row 29 in the column "A" on the sheet `Monthly Balance Sheet`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

### Modification points:

- In order to terminate the for loop, please use the break statement.
- When you want to compare the boolean value, you can use `false` and `true` instead of `"false"` and `"true"`, respectively. And in your case, you can also use `if (result) { do something } else { do something }`, because the values are only `true` or `false`.

### Pattern 1:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
var source = ss.getRange ("SnapshotSpreadsheet!A2:L2");
var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Monthly Balance Sheet");
for (i = 2; i < 30; i++) {
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(i - 1, 1);
  var result = destRange.isBlank();
  if (!result) { // Modified
    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(i, 1);
  } else {
    break; // Modified
  }
}
source.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the first empty cell of the column "A" of the sheet `Monthly Balance Sheet` is retrieved by `getDataRegion`.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
var source = ss.getRange ("SnapshotSpreadsheet!A2:L2");
var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Monthly Balance Sheet");
var row = destSheet.getRange("A1").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getNumRows() + 1;
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(row, 1);
source.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
```

### References:

- [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)
- [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)
- [getDataRegion(dimension)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getDataRegion(Dimension))

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: This was perfect, thank you! I could do it in PHP, but not in GAS, lol!

Comment: @Trading Post LLC Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

````
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
var source = ss.getRange ("SnapshotSpreadsheet!A2:L2");
var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Monthly Balance Sheet");
for (i=2; i<30; i++) 
{
  if (destSheet.getRange(i - 1,1).isBlank())
  {
    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(i-1,1);
    break;
  }  
}
source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true})```
````